# Using the format function to name columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The line of code below takes columns that represent each months total sales and averages the sales by quarter.

```
mdf = tdf[sel_cols].resample('3M',axis=1).mean()
```

What I need to do is title the columns with a str (cannot use pandas .Period function).

I attempting to use the following code, but I cannot get it to work.

```
mdf = tdf[sel_cols].resample('3M',axis=1).mean().rename(columns=lambda x: '{:}q{:}'.format(x.year, [1, 2, 3, 4][x.quarter==1]))
```

I want the columns to read... 2000q1, 2000q2, 2000q3, 2000q4, 2001q1,... etc, but keep getting wrong things like 2000q1, 2000q1, 2000q1, 2000q2, 2001q1.

How can I use the .format function to make this work properly.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4][x.quarter==1]` This will only ever return `1` or `2`.  `x.quarter==1` will always evaluate to either `True` or `False`, which translates to index `1` or `0` of the list, respectively.

Comment: @0x5453 ok, that makes sense. Is there anyway to make that count through 1-4 until it runs out of columns?

Comment: What values can `x.quarter` contain?  If it is already formatted in the range 1-4, then you can just use `x.quarter`.  If it is an increasing count, you could probably do `[1, 2, 3, 4][x.quarter % 4]`.  It's hard to say without seeing any example data.

Comment: @0x5453 this almost works the only issue that it causes is that it starts out with 2000q2. How can I code the [x.quarter %  4] to begin on [0] printing 2000q1.

Comment: @0x5453 aslo x is a list of date time basically every month between 2000 and 2016

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to perform the quarter function on the datetime list like so

```
mdf = tdf[sel_cols].resample('3M',axis=1).mean().rename(columns=lambda x: '{:}q{:}'.format(x.year,x.quarter))
```